# MSWord .doc files serverside manipulation

Tags: asp.net, .net

Is there an alternative for manipulating .doc files in dotnet on the serverside (asp.net) that is not the Aspose.Words? All i need is the mailmerge and other basic functionalities.

Comment: Skimming old related questions, it doesn't look like it. I guess you want something cheaper? If you're not doing anything too complex you might be able to write OpenOffice macros to do what you want, but I've had mixed results running OpenOffice on a server - its headless mode isn't quite, and on Linux it does need an X framebuffer to work against, and that's where it reports its error messages too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OpenXML SDK

[some sample here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42221/1954) and [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124)

Comment: Thank you, but i have to manipulate the old MSWord 97/2000 files.

Comment: You'll need install the compatibility pack. I did a class that I put the file extension in parameter, and then, will build a .doc file.
BuildDocument(@"C:\inetpub\\Anuncios\" + NomeArquivo + ".doc", lista, tipo);

Comment: You also can take a look at http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your reasons for not wanting Aspose, you could also try something based on OpenOffice/LibreOffice like [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/).  They are multi-platform engines that can produce doc format.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 has Word automation services,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff937659